# Eclipse: Sorting in Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a package structure like this:

```
xxx.problem1
xxx.problem2
...
xxx.problem99
```

The imperfection is the sorting in Eclipse:
xxx.problem10, xxx.problem11, ...  is shown above 
xxx.problem2 in the package explorer.

I would like to see it in this way:

```
xxx.problem1
xxx.problem2
xxx.problem9
xxx.problem10
xxx.problem11
...
```

Is there a possibility to have this more human logical sorting
used in the package explorer?

Comment: Why not `xxx.problem01`, `xxx.problem02` (and so on)?

Comment: Also ... It seems that "problem 1", "problem 2" (and so on) are better organized as _projects_, not as _packages_.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: This is a good work around! Quite a lot of renamings, but this can be done by some short code.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't sort packages like that.

If you want to rename, you can do a global regex replace and replace:

```
\.problem([0-9][.;])
```

With:

```
\.problem0$1
```